# MySQL SUM 0 for no result on JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I have two tables, 'authorization' and 'transaction'.

**authorization** table

```
Auth_ID | User_ID | Auth_Hours
-------------------------------
5       | 1       | 60
6       | 2       | 40
7       | 3       | 50
```

**transaction** table

```
Auth_ID | User_ID | Used_Hours
-------------------------------
5       | 1       | 5
6       | 2       | 2
5       | 1       | 20
6       | 2       | 17
5       | 1       | 11
6       | 2       | 9
```

I want my query to sum **Used_Hours** and group by **Auth_ID** and **User_ID** from the transaction table. Here's the catch - I also want the query result to show users who have not used any of their **Auth_Hours** with a 0. See below:

**QUERY**

```
SELECT a.Auth_ID, a.USER_ID, a.Auth_Hours, SUM(t.Used_Hours)
FROM AUTHORIZATION a
JOIN TRANSACTION t
on a.Auth_ID = t.Auth_ID
and a.User_ID = t.User_ID
GROUP BY a.Auth_ID, a.USER_ID, a.Auth_Hours
```

**Actual Result**

```
Auth_ID | User_ID | Auth_Hours | Total Hours Used
-------------------------------------------------
5       | 1       | 60         | 36
6       | 2       | 40         | 28
```

**Wanted Result**

```
Auth_ID | User_ID | Auth_Hours | Total Hours Used
-------------------------------------------------
5       | 1       | 60         | 36
6       | 2       | 40         | 28
7       | 3       | 50         | 0
```

I would imagine the query to be relatively simple.

Comment: Edit your question and show your query.  Then replace the `JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I entered my query. I'll try with LEFT JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JOIN` statement is a shortcut for `INNER JOIN` which returns records that have matching values in both tables. If you want to return **all** records from one table and the matching records from the other table, then you should use an outer join (`LEFT [OUTER] JOIN` or `RIGHT [OUTER] JOIN`). Then you can use the `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()`functions to convert `NULL`s to zeros:

```
SELECT a.Auth_ID, a.USER_ID, a.Auth_Hours, IFNULL(SUM(t.Used_Hours), 0) AS 'Total Hours Used'
FROM authorization a
LEFT JOIN transaction t ON a.Auth_ID = t.Auth_ID AND a.User_ID = t.User_ID
GROUP BY a.Auth_ID, a.USER_ID, a.Auth_Hours
```

Notice that I used single quotes to assign a string with spaces as a name to the total field (as you used in your examples). This will work in all databases. In MySQL you can also use back ticks, but that only works in MySQL.

Here is a [good illustration about the different types of joining tables](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

Comment: Thanks for the help! It looks like IFNULL() is the MySQL equivalent of ISNULL(). Either way, you rock. If you update your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Yes, in MySQL you can use either the `IFNULL()` function or the `COALESCE()` function.

Answer (score 0):

this query work in any mysql Engine or Version. use this query:

```
SELECT a.Auth_ID, a.USER_ID, a.Auth_Hours, CASE COUNT(t.Used_Hours) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE SUM(t.Used_Hours) END AS 'Total Hours Used'
FROM authorization a
LEFT JOIN TRANSACTION t ON a.Auth_ID = t.Auth_ID AND a.User_ID = t.User_ID
GROUP BY a.Auth_ID, a.USER_ID, a.Auth_Hours
```

Comment: COUNT() only records the number of instances, not the actual sum.

Comment: in else of when i return sum(t.Used_Hours). if its helpfull tell me